# Extract file extension from String using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String:

```
"data:audio/mp3;base64,ABC..."
```

And I'm extracting the file extension (in this case `"mp3"`) out of it.

The String varies accordingly to the file type. Some examples:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,ABC..."
"data:image/png;base64,ABC..."
"data:audio/wav;base64,ABC..."
"data:audio/mp3;base64,ABC..."
```

Here's how I've done:

```
public class Test {

    private static final String BASE64_HEADER_EXP = "^data:.+;base64,";

    private static final Pattern PATTERN_BASE64_HEADER = Pattern.compile(BASE64_HEADER_EXP);

    private String data;

    private String fileName;

    public String getFileName() {
        Matcher base64HeaderMatcher = PATTERN_BASE64_HEADER.matcher(data);
        return String.format("%s.%s", getFilenameWithoutExtension(), getExtension(base64HeaderMatcher));
    }

    private String getFilenameWithoutExtension() {
        return fileName.split("\\.")[0];
    }

    private String getExtension(Matcher base64HeaderMatcher) {
        if (base64HeaderMatcher.find()) {
            String base64Header = base64HeaderMatcher.group(0);
            return base64Header.split("/")[1].split(";")[0];
        }
        return fileName.split("\\.")[1];
    }

}
```

What I want is a way to do it without having to split and access array positions like I'm doing above. Maybe extract the extension using a regex expression.

I'm able to do it on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) site using this expression:

```
(?<=^data:.*/)(.*)(?=;)
```

But, when trying to use the same regex on Java, I get the error `"Require that the characters immediately before the position do"` because, aparently, Java doesn't support repetition inside lookbehind:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using capturing groups?

```
private static final String BASE64_HEADER_EXP = "^data:[^/]+/([^;]+);base64,";
```

This way you can use `base64HeaderMatcher.group(1)` and get file type.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for the examples you gave:

```
(?<=data:)(?:[A-z]+)/(.*?);
```

Explanation:

Positive look-behind

```
(?<=data:)
```

Non-capturing group to account for `image`, `audio`, etc.

```
(?:[A-z]+)
```

Match `/` literally, capture group for file extension, match `;` literally

```
/(.*?);
```

Answer (score 0):

"Strings in Java have built-in support for regular expressions. Strings have four built-in methods for regular expressions, i.e., the matches(), split()), replaceFirst() and replaceAll() methods."
-http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Using This Info We can quickly make a regex and test it against our string.

```
//In regex each set of () represents a capture field which can later be 
//referenced with $1, $2 etc..
//The below regex breaks the string into four fields 

string pattern="(^data:)(\\w+?/)(\\w+?)(;.*$)";

//First Field
//This field matches the start of a line (^) followed by "data:"

//Second Field
//This matches any wordCharacter (\\w), one or more (+) followed by a "/"
// the "?" symbol after the + means reluctantly match, match as few 
//characters 
//as possible. this field will effectively capture a seriece of letters 
//followed by a slash

//Third Field
//This is the field we want to capture and we will reference with $3
//it matches any wordCharacter(\\w), one or more reluctantly

//Fourth Field
//This captures the rest of the string including the ";"


//Now to extract the extension from this test string

string test="data:image/jpeg;base64,ABC...";
string testExtension="";

//Replace the contents of testExtension with the 3rd capture field of 
//our regex pattern applied to our test string like so

testExtension = test.replaceAll(pattern, "$3");

//This invokes the String class replaceAll() method 

//And now our string testExtension should contain "jpeg"
```